# CSS multiple child selectors vs single tag selector performance

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Theoretically CSS child selectors are more efficient than tag selectors. But what happens when you have a class and you need to style a specific tags inside this class element but they aren't a first level child?

Let's see an example:

```
.styled-table > tbody > tr > td{
    // Some cell styles
}
```

VS

```
.styled-table td{
    // Some cell styles
}
```

Which of these is a better CSS performance practice?

Comment: "But what happens when you have a class and you need to style a specific tags inside this class element but they aren't a first level child?" Then performance becomes completely irrelevant.

Comment: CSS is read from right to left by interpreter, shorter selectors === more performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS#Avoid_the_descendant_selector.21): Avoid the descendant selector.~</s>

> **The descendant selector is the most expensive selector in CSS.** It is *dreadfully* expensive—especially if the selector is in the Tag or Universal Category.

If you think it through logically, with a descendant selector, the CSS engine will check each child of the parent element (in this case `.styled-table`) looking for matches (in this case the `td` tag) and then each child of those children and so on and so forth.

With a child selector, though, you're telling the engine exactly which "path" to follow to look for a match. If it fails to find a match at any point in the path (e.g., if your `.styled-table` does not have a `tbody` as one of its immediate children) then it will abandon the selector.

Comment: The link you posted to MDN documentation report also that those guidelines were written in 2000 and are/can be no longer relevant to modern browsers.

Comment: Oops, I knew that, but when it popped up on Google, it had a date of January 15th 2016 so I assumed it had been updated. A bit more Googling does reveal that both selectors still have poor performance, relative to other selectors, and that the child selector performs better than the descendant selector.

Comment: Browsers parse selectors from right to left, not from left to right. In other words, they check each child's parent upwardly.